# can't deploy jhipster-registry with heroku

Tags: heroku, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I tried to deploy the default jhipster registry by using the button [deploy to heroku](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/jhipster/jhipster-registry) but it failed.

Can anyone help me please ?

parameters:

**App name**
myapp-registry

**Choose a region** United states

**JHIPSTER_PASSWORD** ******

**JAVA_OPTS**
-Xmx256m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

**MAVEN_CUSTOM_OPTS**
-Pprod,heroku -DskipTests

**NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION**
false

logs:

> ```
>    binding.target.mk:115: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o' failed
>    make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
>    make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_e5224961c3b8d6585d4f090ac485ceae/node_modules/node-sass/build'
>    gyp ERR! build error
>    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
>    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_e5224961c3b8d6585d4f090ac485ceae/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:285:23)
>    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:225:12)
>    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1014-aws
>    gyp ERR! command
>    "/tmp/build_e5224961c3b8d6585d4f090ac485ceae/.heroku/node/bin/node"
>    "/tmp/build_e5224961c3b8d6585d4f090ac485ceae/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
>    "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
>    "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
>    gyp ERR! cwd > 
>    /tmp/build_e5224961c3b8d6585d4f090ac485ceae/node_modules/node-sass
>    gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
>    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
>    gyp ERR! not ok
>    Build failed with error code: 1
>    -----> Build failed
>
>    We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
>    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
>
>    Some possible problems:
>
>    - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
>    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
>
>    Love,
>    Heroku
>      !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.  !     Push failed
> ```

Comment: I was able to reproduce this problem. It looks like it happens because Heroku uses Node 10. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7551#issuecomment-386616407

Answer (score 1):

This issue resulted from an incompatibility with Node 10.  It was fixed in the JHipster Registry code by this [pull request](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/pull/270).  The Deploy to Heroku button now works correctly

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by node-saas which didn't manage to download a valid binary for your environment so it is trying to rebuild the C++ code from scratch which seems like it's not available in the Heroku runner.

Please upgrade to node-saas v4.9.0 which is the first version that supports Node 10: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.9.0